# If k is a singular cardinal then there is no nonprincipal k-complete ideal over k.

Tags: set-theory, ideals, cardinals

The problem stated in the subject is the exercise 7.7 of Thomas Jechs Set theory.  Problem statement:
If $\omega_\alpha$ is singular, then there is no nonprincipal $\omega_\alpha$-complete ideal over $\omega_\alpha$.
I've thought about this problem for a few days now but i can't seem to solve it. Any kind of hint would do, anything to push me in the right direction. Thanks.
P.S. The problem used to have a hint... Atleast until my older brother crossed them out to annihilation with his pen. So if anybody has the hint of the book i would be grateful if you shared that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch:
Suppose that $\mathcal I$ is a nonprincipal $\kappa$-closed ideal on $\kappa$.
First show that
$$
\mathcal P_{< \kappa}(\kappa) := \{ X \subseteq \kappa \mid \mathrm{card}(X) < \kappa \} \subseteq \mathcal{I}.
$$

Now observe the following: Since $\kappa$ is singular, there is some $\gamma < \kappa$ and a sequence $(X_i \mid i< \gamma)$ of sets $X_i \in \mathcal P_{< \kappa}(\kappa)$ such that
$$
\kappa = \bigcup_{i < \gamma} X_i.
$$
By the step above we have $X_i \in \mathcal I$. But, since $\gamma < \kappa$, this contradicts the fact that $\mathcal I$ is $\kappa$-closed.

Comment: I understand everything up until the contradiction. Can you explain why please?

Comment: @shervin If $\mathcal I$ is an ideal on $\kappa$ then, by definition, $\kappa \not \in \mathcal I$.

Comment: Oh thanks i thought the contradiction was "Entirely" related to I being k-closed. :)

Comment: @shervin It is related to $\mathcal I$ being $\kappa$-closed. Only because $\mathcal I$ is $\kappa$-closed and $\{ X_i \mid i < \gamma \} \subseteq \mathcal I$ can we conclude that $\kappa \in \mathcal I$.

Comment: Corrected my comment.